# Does openshift 3.11 support ipvs proxy mode?

Tags: openshift

I am setting up a new Openshift system with origin v3.11. The only information provided in the official website is: Disabling Features Using Feature Gates. And in the Service Proxy Mode section of the document it says there are only two proxy-mode supported, so I am not sure if the ipvs mode is removed.
I think kuberntes 1.11 has the IPVS as proxy mode supported and the openshift 3.11 is based on k8s 1.11:

Kubelet Version:            v1.11.0+d4cacc0
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.11.0+d4cacc0

Does anyone ever tried to enable the IPVS proxy mode on openshift 3.11? I have tried to modify the master-config.yaml and node-config.yaml files. And tried to modify the config map.I added something like:

```
feature-gates:
    - SupportIPVSProxyMode=true
```

```
proxyArguments:
  cluster-cidr:
  - 10.128.0.0/14
  proxy-mode:
  - ipvs
  ipvs-min-sync-period:
  - 5s
  ipvs-sync-period:
  - 5s
  ipvs-scheduler:
  - rr
```

And then restarted the master and node service.
Also I have the ipvsadm installed on all nodes.

But, it seems not to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenShift only supports two [service proxy modes](https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/core_concepts/pods_and_services.html#service-proxy-mode):

1. iptables
2. userspace

In general, OpenShift by design only supports a subset of upstream Kubernetes  features (though in some cases, such as [route objects](https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/networking/routes.html) or the [web console](https://docs.okd.io/latest/getting_started/developers_console.html), OpenShift has extra features).

These features are cherry picked by Red Hat engineering based on stability, supportabitily, and customer demand.